# SQL CASE with Alias

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to change a column name based on the results of a case statement, is this possible and how would I do it...here is what I have so far but I am not good enough at SQL yet.

I want the change the column name of VALUE to become NUMVALUE if the data is numeric and ALNVALUE if the data isn't numeric.  Essentially making a three column datatable a four column datatable.  Is this possible?

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Value])=1 THEN SELECT [VALUE] AS [NUMVALUE] ELSE SELECT [VALUE] AS [ALNVALUE] END
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need two CASEs = two columns:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Value])= 1 THEN [VALUE] END AS [NUMVALUE],
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Value])<>1 THEN [VALUE] END AS [ALNVALUE],
...
FROM myTable
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need ... thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible.

Think about the issues you'd run into when you try and use the result set.  Anytime you tried to access the data, you would get an exception stating that the column couldn't be found or similar.

`Dim data = Results["ColumnName"]` would become unreliable.

You will need to make a separate column for each of them or put them all under the same name.